# "Switch-App" simulation using Touch Injection API in Windows 8 - C++ code

Tags: touch

A simple way to switch between application in Windows 8 is "Swipe Right" using the touch screen (put down one finger in the left side of the screen and move it a few pixels to the right). I'm trying to simulate this behavior using [Touch Injection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802896%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but the switch app behavior is not invoked although the feedback shows the swipe is actually happening.
Here's the code I ran:

```
int main()
{ 
    //Screen Resolution 1366x768
    BOOL ret = TRUE;

    //init
    InitializeTouchInjection(10, TOUCH_FEEDBACK_INDIRECT);
    POINTER_TOUCH_INFO contact = {0};
    memset(&contact, 0, sizeof(POINTER_TOUCH_INFO));

    contact.pointerInfo.pointerType = PT_TOUCH;
    contact.pointerInfo.pointerId = 0;

    //set start point (a point at the left side of the screen)
    contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = 768/2;
    contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = 0;

    contact.touchFlags = TOUCH_FLAG_NONE;
    contact.touchMask = TOUCH_MASK_CONTACTAREA | TOUCH_MASK_ORIENTATION | TOUCH_MASK_PRESSURE;
    contact.orientation = 90;
    contact.pressure = 32000;

    contact.rcContact.top = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y -2;
    contact.rcContact.bottom = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y + 2;
    contact.rcContact.left = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x -2;
    contact.rcContact.right = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x + 2;

    //set flags for "start touch"
    contact.pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_DOWN | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;

    ret = InjectTouchInput(1, &contact);

    cout << "X: " << contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x << " Y: " << contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y << endl;
    if(ret != TRUE)
    {
        cout << "Error 1: " << GetLastError() <<endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        //set flags for "update"
        contact.pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;

        //move the location one pixel right
        contact.rcContact.bottom = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x++;

        ret = InjectTouchInput(1, &contact);

        cout << "X: " << contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x << " Y: " << contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y << endl;
        if(ret != TRUE)
        {
            cout << "Error 2: " << GetLastError() <<endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //set flags for "end touch"
    contact.pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UP;

    ret = InjectTouchInput(1, &contact);

    cout << "X: " << contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x << " Y: " << contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y << endl;
    if(ret != TRUE)
    {
        cout << "Error 3: " << GetLastError() <<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any idea why this code doesn't behave as expected?

By the way, same happens when trying to "Swipe Left" to open Charms-Bar

The code is written relating on [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6460.simulating-touch-input-in-windows-8-using-touch-injection-api.aspx) article

Comment: afaik this sample does not work anymore with RTM version of 8 - thought it might have something to do with POINTER_FLAG_PRIMARY, but had no success ether. same problem here